# Microsoft Identity Server - Email 2FA

Tags: identityserver4

We are using Microsoft Identity Server and we are using email 2FA but we are unsure of the lifespan of the email PIN. From what I have read in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity), the email PIN is valid for six minutes but when we are testing and from our testing, I am  asking for a  PIN at 1:00:00 and I get an email with the PIN to login. If I try to login seven minutes after, at 1:07:02 I am still able to login even though the PIN is valid for six minutes.

[image]

Does anybody here know how long does an email PIN is valid for?

Comment: How have you configured your token provider?